# Can I add content stored in a const to addText() function in officegen-docx?

Tags: node.js, npm, node-modules, docx

In order to create a file in docx, we need to use

```
const p=docx.createP();
p.addText("Hi");
```

As I have my data stored in const and I need to know the way to add text from a constant,
or any other function.

I tried adding variable name

```
p.addText(content); //const content
```

it throws error : ReferenceError: content is not defined.

Comment: If you're encountering a ReferenceError stating that content is not defined, it means that the content variable is not accessible within the scope of where you're trying to use it. Where and how did you define content? need to see more code